# Key Value Coding clarification

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-coding

From Apple's documentation I came across the following:

> Setting values using key paths is not the same as setting them using
>   Objective-C properties. You cannot use property notation to set
>   transform values. You must use the setValue:forKeyPath: method with
>   the preceding key path strings.

From my understanding, we must have properties of our ivars in order to use KVC.

But from the paragraph above, it seems to say otherwise:

*Setting values using key paths **is not the same** as setting them using
Objective-C properties. You **cannot use property notation** to set
transform values.*

Can someone explain to me why? Perhaps I am missing something, because all along my understanding is that we must have properties to utilize KVC.

Comment: I think all it's saying is that this won't work: `setValue:value forKey:@"view.transform`. You'd have to use `setValue:value forKeyPath:@view.transform`.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets You meant without the double quotes but keeping the **@** sign?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. I meant the `forKeyPath` part, as opposed to just `forKey`.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Sorry, didn't quite get you. You mean: `setValue:value forKeyPath:view.transform`? This wouldn't work.

Comment: No, it would be (without typos this time): `[self setValue:value forKeyPath:@"view.transform"]`. `view` is a property on `self`.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Aren't they both (i.e. `forKeyPath` and `forKey`) KVC compliant? Mind citing the difference? Perhaps I missed something here.

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValue:forKeyPath: *keyPath
A key path of the form relationship.property (with one or more relationships): for example "department.name" or "department.manager.lastName".* You can't do "department.name" in `setValue:forKey:`, you need `setValue:forKeyPath:` for that.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets Will definitely read up. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding, we must have properties of our ivars in order to use KVC.

This is incorrect. KVC will use the property generated accessor methods, or other (appropriately named) accessor methods if they exist, but they aren't required. If they don't exist KVC will attempt to directly access the instance variables.

Check [this Apple ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA) for a description of how KVC searches for the key to update.

Comment: Thanks, but what would be a  _"..other (appropriately named) accessor methods"_? Can you cite an example regarding this?

Comment: For setting only the set<Key>: method is actually valid, then instance variable names matching the pattern _<key>, _is<Key>, <key>, or is<Key>, in that order.